# Images not displaying on a website deployed to server

Tags: php

Can somebody explain to me why isn't this image displaying when I uploaded my website to the server?

`<img src="<?php echo __DIR__."/id-14.png" ?>" alt="[profile picture]">`

The image is in the same folder as the `.php` file.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

What is being displayed is the '[profile picture]' text.

Comment: if you have access to the terminal of the server, check whether directory and files have the read permission

Comment: I believe they do, because accessing the stylesheet and javascript files goes without any problems

Comment: if you inspect it in the browser, what's the url path assigned to src ?

Comment: using \__DIR__ would give a server path which only server can access. If you put that path to browser rendering elements it will fail. Use \__DIR__ for only server side work. Images are ultimately rendered by the browser and will fail to load that path at the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use a http path for image because ultimately its rendered in client's browser and client's browser engine check for the path.

If we use __DIR__ it will give a local path like **'/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main'** which will work fine with your local machine but when deployed client's browser can't access.

Since you know the directory path and its exposed to outside,

```
<?php $path = "http://host/images"; ?>
<img src="<?=$path."/id-14.png" ?>" alt="[profile picture]">
```

I used a variable there because its easier if you have multiple places it use 
__DIR__

Comment: That's a good advice which I will apply. But even after changing the way of providing a path name it still doesn't work. I have even put the image file in the same directory as the `.php` file and tried accessing it without a success.

Comment: When I changed it to `src="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."id-14" ?>"`, the url path assigned to it in the page source is as follows: `src="http://mjnoach2.ayz.pl/id-14"` which is correct.
When I browse to this url manually, the browser downloads a file named id-14, but it is not recognised by a photo preview software.

Comment: @manjii how do you upload that image to the server? I think the file is corrupted when uploading. Check whether the file has been uploaded correctly.

Comment: You are probably right. Now I have uploaded an image to the server manually and changed the src path to access it and it worked just fine. 
Can the problem be that I am saving the file without the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and  `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` + `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

change this :

```
<img src="<?php echo __DIR__."/id-14.png" ?>" alt="[profile picture]">
```

to this

```
<img src="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/id-14.png" ?>" alt="[profile picture]">
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is with the `.htaccess`? But the RewriteCondition that I used should allow for accessing files...

Comment: yep, that would be appliyed on all file on your server